# MySQL convert table from Latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql

I need to convert a table with a lot of data from Latin1 to utf8 so that it can accept Korean characters.  How do I alter that table without corrupting the data that's in there?  What would my SQL statement be?  What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export (dump) the database, and reimport it with the new encoding.

http://alexking.org/blog/2008/03/06/mysql-latin1-utf8-conversion

Answer (score 12):

`ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`